# Making a dict vector collecting string from an array using python/scikit/pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy, scikit-learn

I have a dataset of some experimental data sheet of some of my experiment. I have an array which contains say 5 columns and 100 rows. Out of them 4 columns contain floating point numbers while the rest one say column 4th contain names of some reactants/chemicals  (i.e. strings). It may happen one name has many duplicates in other rows. I want to make a vector like dictionary which will be like say {'name1':0, 'name2':1,...}. Duplicate strings won't be added in this vector. I searched through past questions, yet I could not solve the problem.

Sample Data: (only some data are provided from huge mother data)

```
Id,R1Test,R2Test,P1Test,Reactant,CC
0,1.2,3.2,5.2,Contra+1a,3.0
1,3.4,0.1,8.9,Sepi+1a,4.3
2,2.3,3.8,8.9,Sepi+1a,2.1
3,1.2,3.4,6.0,Drav2,1.2
4,-2.1,-1.0,9.8,Contra-1a,77.0
5,7.0,0.2,0.3,Contra+1a,2.5
```

Any handle?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to post a small example showing your array/DataFrame and state what the expected output should be?

Comment: Say for example, structure of my data seems like this: [Id,R1Test,R2Test,P1Test,Reactant,CC
{0,1.2,3.2,5.2,Contra+1a,3.0}
{1,3.4,0.1,8.9,Sepi+1a,4.3}
{2,2.3,3.8,8.9,Sepi+1a,2.1}
{3,1.2,3.4,6.0,Drav2,1.2}
{4,-2.1,-1.0,9.8,Contra-1a,77.0}
{5,7.0,0.2,0.3,0.2,Contra+1a,2.5}]

Comment: I want create a python dictionary sort of array like {'Contra+1a':0, 'Sepi+1a':1,...}.

Comment: Please put the sample data in the question itself (not comments) and format the code and data by clicking ```{}``` or surrounding with 3 backticks ( ` ).

Comment: @JohnE I have already provided sample data. <br/> Id,R1Test,R2Test,P1Test,Reactant,CC <br/>  0,1.2,3.2,5.2,Contra+1a,3.0 <br/> 1,3.4,0.1,8.9,Sepi+1a,4.3 <br/> 2,2.3,3.8,8.9,Sepi+1a,2.1 <br/> 3,1.2,3.4,6.0,Drav2,1.2 <br/> 4,-2.1,-1.0,9.8,Contra-1a,77.0 <br/> 5,7.0,0.2,0.3,0.2,Contra+1a,2.5 <br/>  I want to see a vector like 'Contra+1a':0, 'Sepi+1a':1,... so that the strings have been taken automatically ( I do not want to put by pd.Series), uniqely and indexed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you ask is dict(name: index of first occurrence). If that's the case,
here's what you may use:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> namesCol = pd.Series(list('abac'))
>>> namesCol
0    a
1    b
2    a
3    c
dtype: object
```

the desired dict would be

```
corresp = dict(a = 0, b = 1, c = 3)
```

Get unique names:

```
>>> names = namesCol.unique()
>>> names
array(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype=object)
```

Now find the first occurrences for each name:

```
>>> corresp = {name: namesCol[namesCol == name].index[0] for name in names}
>>> corresp
{'a': 0, 'c': 3, 'b': 1}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are right that I am asking dict with first occurrence. However, my confusion is that when I am listing 'abc' this means I am entering this data. My data contains say 14450 samples. I wanted to do it automatically so that I do not need to enter the list('abc') by hand. The python code would scan each row of for the particular column data and if it is the first occurrence then would add in dict. Is it possible? It is easier in C/C++. However, I am searching for Python.

Comment: @vega: I assumed you're somewhat familiar with Python/pandas and have your "dataset of some experimental data sheet" as pandas dataframe or at least numpy array. From your comment I conclude that you do not. If your data is in .csv file you can get it via `myData = pd.read_csv(pathToCSV)` and then get your `namesCol = myData[nameOfColWithNames]`.

Comment: I read the csv file using pandas and so I tagged the question for Pandas also.

Comment: If you have your data in pandas dataframe, so why do you ask how not to enter listsing 'abc' manually?

Comment: I think you did not understand problem. I can use pandas. Now I want to make a dict like {string1:0, string2:1,...} from the text field of the data shown. There may be repeated strings. I do not want to make Series by hand coding as there are many strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
labels, uniques = pd.vectorize(s['Reactant'])
```

this will return the unique values you have and the labels for that column ...

If you just need a dictionary and not to substitute them or what ever as you are asking you can do the following:

```
dictionary = {value: i for i, value in enumerate(s['Reactant'].unique())}
```

looping over unique values and assign an integer to each one.

Comment: A brief explanation of what this code does would be helpful.